# Uninitialized constant Person_instance (NameError)

Tags: ruby

My Ruby Code...

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :age, :gender
    person_instance = Person.new
    person_instance.name = "Konstantin"
    person_instance.age = 19
    person_instance.gender = "male"
end
puts person_instance.age
```

My Error In Ruby...

```
C:/Users/Balu/RubymineProjects/learning/test:10:in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Person_instance (NameError)
from -e:1:in 'load'
from -e:1:in '<main>'
```

Process finished with `exit code 1`.

Comment: local variable is not accessible outside class, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Use it in the following way

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :gender
end
person_instance = Person.new
person_instance.name = "Konstantin"
person_instance.age = 19
person_instance.gender = "male"
puts person_instance.age
```

You basically need to declare your instance, once your class is declared.